# Keep vs retain vs maintain for product features

Tags: word-choice, word-request

I want to describe a new product which is an improved version of an existing one. The new product has all the features from the existing product, and adds a few new features.

I am looking for a nice way to phrase the above, specifically the verb which is used to say that the new products has all the features from the previous one:

- Product X keeps all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- Product X retains all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- Product X maintains all the features from product Y, and adds ...
- ... other?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Product Y can keep or [retain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/retain) its own features, for example after some kind of upgrade, but product X can't keep or retain the features of product Y, because they belong to product Y.

However, if product Y can be considered to be an "upgrade" of product X (e.g. iPhone 6 vs iPhone 5), then **retain** would be valid.

None of the meanings of [maintain](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/maintain) are suitable either.

You can keep it simple by just using **have**:

> Product X **has** all the features **of** product Y, and adds...

Note that [features](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/feature) are properties **of** something, so you need to use the preposition **of** rather than **from**.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Re. this: "product X can't keep or retain the features of product Y, because they belong to product Y" -- does that apply even when product X is a variation of product Y? Think for example iPhone 6 vs iPhone 5.

Comment: As I mentioned, retain is appropriate if it can be viewed as "some kind of upgrade", so Iphone 5 -> iphone 6 would count, even if the technologies used in these two versions are completely different. Macbook Pro -> Macbook Air would not count, as they are completely different product lines.

Comment: OK. In my case, the new product is an improved version of an existing one. If iPhone5 -> iPhone 6 counts as an "upgrade" and would allow the use of retain, then that should also be appropriate for my case.

Comment: If you can edit your answer to include this observation then I will happily mark it as accepted.